# How to stub with a different function on subsequent calls to sinon.js stub

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon

I'm trying to write a test where I need to have a function stubbed with a different function depending on whether it's the first time it's being called or the second time. So far I've tried:

```
  this.dispatcherStub = sinon.stub(alt.dispatcher, 'dispatch');

  this.dispatcherStub.onFirstCall().returns((dataArgs) => {
    // Some assertion on the data
  });

  this.dispatcherStub.onSecondCall().returns((dataArgs) => {
    // Another assertion on the data
    done();
  });
```

Note that I need them to be different functions, not merely different return different values as I require mocha's done() to be called within the second function as it is being called asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *execute* the functions returned:

```
this.dispatcherStub = sinon.stub(alt.dispatcher, 'dispatch');

  this.dispatcherStub.onFirstCall().returns(
      (function () {}();
  });

  this.dispatcherStub.onSecondCall().returns((dataArgs) => {  
    (function () {
        done();
    }();
  });
```

You can also turn an arrow function into an IIFE by using `(() => return 4)();`